# Is there a way of constraining keyof type to result in a Function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a wrapper function which takes a class instance, a name of a method, an argument object, and then it should call that method on the instance.

I want the second argument (method name) to be constrained in some way so that it is actually a callable method on the instance. Something like this is what I am trying:

```js
const doWrapped = <C, K extends keyof C, C[K] extends Function>(
    instance: C, name: K, arg: Parameters<C[K]>[0]
  ): ReturnType<C[K]> => {
  return instance[name](arg);
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to define the constraints correctly.

Edit after kellys comment: To clarify; in my specific case all methods take only one argument, and that can be a part of the constraint, but a more general solution would also be welcome.

Edit2: This is what I have now

```
const doWrapped = <K extends keyof C, A, R, C extends { K: (arg0: A) => R }>(
        instance: C, name: K, arg: A
    ): R => {
    return instance[name](arg);
}
```

But it results in `2349: This expression is not callable.  Type 'unknown' has no call signatures.`.
Even though the type of `instance` seem to be `(parameter) instance: C extends { K: (args: A) => R; }` as specified.

Comment: How is this safe? You only allow the first parameter to be given but if a function expects multiple that leads to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: It isnt, the constraints I have now isnt even working at all, I specifically ask how we should define constraints to make this typecheck. I know that my methods will take only one argument, so that should also be a part of the constraint (and make it "safe").

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible (both with a unary function and with a generic `invoke` facility):

```js
type CallableViewOf<C> = {
  [K in keyof C as UnaryFunction<C[K], K>]: UnaryFunction<C[K]> /* this assertion is necessary for TS to follow what we're doing */;
}

type UnaryFunction<Test, ReturnType = Test> = Test extends (...args: infer Args) => unknown
  ? Args['length'] extends 1 ? ReturnType : never : never;

function invoke<
  C,
  Viable extends CallableViewOf<C> = CallableViewOf<C>,
  K extends keyof Viable = keyof Viable>
  (thing: C, operation: K, arg: Parameters<Viable[K]>[0]): ReturnType<Viable[K]> {
  return (thing as any)[operation](arg);
}
```

The unary version and the multi-arg version only differ in their definitions of `invoke` and `CallableViewOf`:

```js
type CallableViewOf2<C> = {
  [K in keyof C as IsFunction<C[K], K>]: C[K] extends (...x: any) => any ? C[K] : never/* this assertion is necessary for TS to follow what we're doing */;
}

type IsFunction<Test, ReturnType = Test> = Test extends (...args: any) => any ? ReturnType : never;

function invoke2<
  C,
  Viable extends CallableViewOf2<C> = CallableViewOf2<C>,
  K extends keyof Viable = keyof Viable>
  (thing: C, operation: K, ...args: Parameters<Viable[K]>): ReturnType<Viable[K]> {
  return (thing as any)[operation](...(args as any));
}
```

```js
// Examples
class Foo {
  public fooField = "Hello!";
  bar(x: number): string {
    return x.toString(2)
  }
  boom(): 77 {
    return 77;
  }
  boom2(x: number, y: number): number {
    return x + y;
  }
}

const Bar = {
  aProperty: 123,
  boom(): 33 {
    return 33;
  },
  baz(hmm: string): boolean {
    return hmm.length > 3;
  },
  bam(hmm: number): string {
    return `${hmm}`;
  },
  ohBoy(x: number, y: string): boolean {
    return x.toString() === y;
  }
}


// A single parameter function can be invoked
const result = invoke(Bar, "baz", '123');
// A multi-parameter function can be invoked
const result2 = invoke2(Bar, "ohBoy", 1, 'cool!');
```

Comment: Excellent! This solves the actual problem of constraining the input parameters!
For full marks I would like to not have to use `any` in the invoke body though.
Is that possible? We should be able to constrain it at the call site to be a function as well right? With this solution it says `Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'C'.`
Why is that?